# What does it mean to describe a joke as ジェネギャ?

Tags: translation, jokes

> ジェネギャなジョーク

Need help with translating the phrase above to English.
I know it is some kind of joke and Google Translate is not helping much.

Comment: ジェネギャ is probably an abbreviation for ジェネレーション・ギャップ (genearation gap).

Comment: Sounds like a newer way to say 親父ギャーグ

Answer (score 4):

[marasai](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/3506/marasai) wrote in [a comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23302/what-does-it-mean-to-describe-a-joke-as-%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%8D%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A3#comment49483_23302):

> ジェネギャ is probably an abbreviation for ジェネレーション・ギャップ (generation gap).

Comment: I think if you copy a comment verbatim you should give credit to the original poster and make this answer community wiki.

Answer (score 4):

「ジェネギャ」 is as @marasai stated in the comments above.

I had to google around, however, to find out what 「ジェネギャ**な**」 means as an adjective as no one around me uses it.  Fortunately, I was able to find enough example usages to conclude that:

> 「ジェネギャ**な**」 is synonymous to 「[時代遅]{じだいおく}れな」.

Thus,

> 「ジェネギャなジョーク」 should mean "**outdated or old-fashioned kind of jokes**".